# How to add an activity to WindowManager

Tags: android

I am writing an android library that needs to display an activity on top of the client app. After some reading up it seems that adding a new window is what I want to do so I added in this permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

I then try to add an image view by doing this

```
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 10;
        params.y = 100;

        ImageView imageview = new ImageView(this);

        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
        windowManager.addView( imageview , params);
```

But what I want is to have my own activity on this new window on top of the client apps window. is this even possible? How would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok the correct approach to this appears to be to inflate the layout with in the service class and add it to the windowmanager that way. Then create a regular java class that can be used as the event listeners for the actions within that layout. I didnt need to use fragments or activities.

```
mRootLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).
                inflate(R.layout.myContainerXML, null);
MyListManager myListManager = new MyListManager(mRootLayout,context);

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

ListView listView = (ListView) mRootLayout.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(activity,R.layout.list_row,(ArrayList)myListManager.getList());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

windowManager.addView(mRootLayout, params);
```

If anyone has a better way I would love to hear it thanks

Comment: hi, I'm trying to do something similiar. can you post the code of MyListManager. I see you pass the inflated view to the constructor of the class. but how do you attach the event listeners? are you extending your class with Activity?